# Gnuplot 5.2 does not load script file

Tags: windows-7, gnuplot

I use Gnuplot in windows 7 in terminal wxt to plot several 2-d plots from a data file with 5 columns of time data. Plotting works fine with a simple script file gvx.dat, which is invoked by the command prompt gnuplot: load "gvx.dat". When using an other script file, then an error comes: Cannot open script file 'ddd.dat'. This occurs with every script file, even with a copy gvx-copy.dat of gvx.dat, where the compare command fc indicates no difference between gvx.dat and gvx-copy.dat.
Any idea why it does not work?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In the gnuplot console, if you type `pwd` what does it show? And what is the path of your `gvx.dat` and your `ddd.dat`? What is the content of your script file?

Answer (score 0):

and thanks for your answer.
In gnuplot console after pwd we have  C:\gnuplot\bin   where gnuplot.exe is.
Path of the two script files is as given in the script file, see below.
The script file is:

```
set terminal wxt    
cd '..\..\..\R:\neue-dateien\fam\2012\fortranprogramme'    
pwd    
set title ' Geschwindigkeit über Weg'    
set yrange [0:1]    
set xrange [0:720]    
set xlabel 'Entfernung [km]'    
set ylabel 'Geschwindigkeit [%c]'    
plot 'bislins.dat' using 5:1 with points
```

For me it seems, that one year ago, I used the same data and scripts and they worked well. May be the misbehavior is cause by any change in windows stuff??
Does this help?

Comment: this is not an answer, but more details to the question. So, please edit your question and add this to your question.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your problem:

You are typing `load gvx.dat` in the gnuplot console with the initial working directory (as you say it is `C:\gnuplot\bin`). But in this script you are changing the directory to something else. So, after this script has finished, and if you type `load gvx.dat` again, it will not be able to find it because now you are in a different directory.

You could give the absolute path to your file, e.g.:

```
set terminal wxt    

FILE = 'R:\neue-dateien\fam\2012\fortranprogramme\bislins.dat'

set title ' Geschwindigkeit über Weg'    
set yrange [0:1]    
set xrange [0:720]    
set xlabel 'Entfernung [km]'    
set ylabel 'Geschwindigkeit [%c]'  

plot FILE using 5:1 with points
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with a line FILE= in the script, but it did not work. The main problem is, that no other script file can be loaded, except gvx.dat. If I start gnuplot with a copy of gvx.dat or any other script file in the same directory, the error comes : cannot open script file.
SoI have copied the scripts and the data file into the installation directory C:\gnuplot\bin and now it works. I cannot realize the solution to this problem,  gnuplot cannot find the correct directories or if the script file gvx.dat is such unique and all others are wrong in an invisible way. Any way, I can live with it, by using it inside the bin directory. Therefor I like to end the discussion, thanks for help to all guys!